# Django allauth stopping email confirmation

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

In my web app I am using django-allauth for account management.

If a user gets signed up in my app they will get an email with "confirmation link".(without confirming email they can login but wont get full rights).

Now I want to delay the sending of confirmation email as mean while they can perform some actions which results in updates in a table. If user do those actions( if table gets updated) then only I need to send that confirmation email .I am thinking to use signals here.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from allauth.account.signals import user_signed_up
from allauth.account.utils import send_email_confirmation
from django.dispatch import receiver
import datetime


#this signal will be called when user signs up.
@receiver(user_signed_up, dispatch_uid="some.unique.string.id.for.allauth.user_signed_up")
def user_signed_up_(request, user, **kwargs):

    send_email_confirmation(request, user, signup=True)
    #this allauth util method, which sends confirmation email to user.


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

    are_u_intrested = models.BooleanField(default=False)


models.signals.post_save.connect(user_signed_up_, sender=UserProfile, dispatch_uid="update_stock_count")

#If user fills this userProfile , then I only send confirmation mail.
#If UserProfile model instace saved , then it send post_save signal.
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT-**

One way I could think of was to set `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION` to `"none"`, and then call allauths `send_email_confirmation` method once the user has added those fields to the database.

Comment: I know that setting but , What I want is send email after sometime.

Comment: @user3237836 oh, apologies, I didn't read the question properly.

Comment: :-) Ok but i dont need apologies , Help me.. ;-)

Comment: OK I tried what you said , but I need to call   send_email_confirmation(request, user, signup=True) at some point when post_save signal called. But I dont have request and user instance pass to pass. How can I do that